# How to use one restriction (<xs:minLength value="10"/>) for more than one element

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to use `<restriction>` but I don't want to repeat `<xs:minLength value="10"/>` on every element.

```
<xs:element name="AddressLine1">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="AddressLine2">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="AddressLine3">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the type out into a separate declaration, and then use the `type` attribute of the `<xs:element>` tags to specify which type they should use. Of course, this requires you to name the type you are defining, as I have done here:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="longishString">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="AddressLine1" type="longishString"/>
    <xs:element name="AddressLine2" type="longishString"/>
    <xs:element name="AddressLine3" type="longishString"/>
</xs:schema>
```

The type definition can be located anywhere in the schema; it doesn't matter where it is relative to the elements that have that type.

Comment: @Misuk Glad I could help. If this answer solved your problem, you might like to click on the checkmark to the left beneath the voting buttons to mark it as accepted.